# Automatically abbreviate authors' first names in LaTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex, citations

Using natbib/Latex/Bibtex, in the references section I get references with full first names like:

> Vladimir Iosifovich Levenshtein. Binary codes capable of correcting deletions, insertions, and reversals. Technical Report 8, 1966.

I would like automatically abbreviated first names like:

> V. I. Levenshtein. Binary codes capable of correcting deletions, insertions, and reversals. Technical Report 8, 1966.

If you have an idea how to do this I will be glad to hear.

Comment: Caspar's answer is great, but should be replaced by `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,giveninits=true]{biblatex}` because `firstinits` is declared as deprecated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a BibTeX style that does this.  Alternatively, create your own style by modifying an existing one.  You will have to change the function `format.names`, so that a line similar to this:

```
s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

has `f.` as shown.  The full first name would be shown if it is  `ff`.

Comment: I use the \bibliographystyle{plainnat}, where should I edit the function (in which file?). Thanks!

Comment: @TTT: Copy the file `plainnat.bst` into your working directory under a different name (e.g. `my-plainnat.bst`).  Look for the `FUNCTION {format.names}`.  About the seventh line of that function is the line shown above.  Modify it to `f.` instead of `ff`.  Then, use `\bibliographystyle{my-plainnat}` in your LaTeX file.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Additional step is that you need to update your index. Check out [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages) and scroll down to "4. Update your index" for instructions.

Comment: Should this answer be moved to tex.stackexchange?

Comment: Notice that one need to delete the .bbl file before it works.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Biblatex, just add this in your preable when calling for Biblatex:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
```

Note: For older latex versions: use `firstinits` instead  - `firstinits` was recently replaced by `giveninits`.

Comment: See flipper's comment above: as of 2020, `firstinits` is deprecated and should be replaced by `giveninits`.